# Dynamically add classes to react component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react component

```
const style = {
    "border":"2px solid grey",
    "margin-bottom":"2px",
    "list-style":"none",
    "text-align":"center"
}

const isDoneStyle = {
    "text-decoration":"line-through"
}

export default function Todo({name,isComplete,date}) {

    return (
    <li style={}>
        <p>Task: {name}</p>
        <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={isComplete}/>
        <p>{date}</p>
    </li>
    );
}
```

All the li's should have the `style` class, but only when `isComplete` is true it should have the `isDoneStyle` added. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Boris, just wrote you a solution below, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Boris, I've wrote a solution which is based on defining a function which will calculate the style base on the prop. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that style attributes in React need to be camel-case.

```
const style = {
    border:"2px solid grey",
    marginBottom:"2px",
    listStyle:"none",
    textAlign:"center"
}

const isDoneStyle = {
    textDecoration:"line-through"
}
```

You can use a ternary operator to decide what `style` object to use. Additionally, you can use the spread operator, to combine the properties of the objects you want to use into a single object.

```
<li style={ isComplete ? {...style, ...isDoneStyle} : {...style} }>
    <p>Task: {name}</p>
    <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={isComplete}/>
    <p>{date}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you. The style actually still works even though I don't use camel case.

Comment: I am using nextJs, maybe that is why?

Comment: @BorisGrunwald that explains alot haha. That's awesome. Did the above work for you?

Comment: @BorisGrunwald great! For the record, I think it would make more sense to create a class in your style sheet instead though and refer to that class conditionally. It's just cleaner overall. Please do consider upvoting and marking this as the answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use function to define those styles

```js
const style = {
    "border":"2px solid grey",
    "margin-bottom":"2px",
    "list-style":"none",
    "text-align":"center"
}

const isDoneStyle = {
    "text-decoration":"line-through"
}

const getStyle = isComplete => isComplete ? {...style, ...isDoneStyle} : style

export default function Todo({name,isComplete,date}) {
    return (
    <li style={getStyle(isComplete)}>
        <p>Task: {name}</p>
        <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={isComplete}/>
        <p>{date}</p>
    </li>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of above won't fulfil your requirements think about using classes instead of injecting styling directly into component. I strongly recommend using library called [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) which is designed for resolving problem like yours. I successfully used this library in many projects and it was always the best solution. Your example would like like:

CSS:

```
.main-layout {
    "border":"2px solid grey",
    "margin-bottom":"2px",
    "list-style":"none",
    "text-align":"center"
}

.done-layout {
    "text-decoration":"line-through"
}
```

React:

```
export default function Todo({name,isComplete,date}) {
return (
<li className={
    classNames({
       main-layout: true,
       done-layout: isComplete
    }
>
    <p>Task: {name}</p>
    <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={isComplete}/>
    <p>{date}</p>
</li>
);
}
```

If you doesn't like this approach - don't worry. `classNames` allows you to choose one of few different ways of dynamic styles switching.